# SharePoint Claims trust between HNSC

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication, sts-securitytokenservice, claims

We have to HNSC https://division1.corp.com https://division2.corp.com on the same SPWebApplication using Claims and Forms Authentication. When logging in to https://division1.corp.com we should have access to https://division2.corp, but we get the logon dialog box again. The UserInformationList are synchronized between this HNSC. By looking at the cookie, they are different. 
How shall we solve this?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 out of the box does not provide a way to share authentication between its own web applications.  This is primarily because each application authenticates users independently and the cookies that it issues are marked with the HTTP Only flag.  This means the cookie cannot be accessed by other applications on different DNS names (even if they are part of the same SharePoint farm).

The most common resolution to this is to set up an external federated trusted identity provider (such as ADFS) and have each of your web applications trust it.  Then you can configure your federated identity provider to authenticate against your forms provider.

Here's some more detailed info about how the authentication structure in SharePoint works and how you can develop against it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430136.aspx

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to configure federated trust without using ADFS. This article "Claims-Based Single Sign-On for Microsoft SharePoint 2010" [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446525.aspx) walks you through an example of integrating two web applications into a sso environment for intranet and extranet web users. The article describes how to configure a New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer where you can add ProviderRealms to SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer. In our scenario we set -SignInUrl https://division.corp.com/_layouts/fba/fbalogin.aspx. But I cant find out how to configure the section federatedAuthentication.